# How to get group by work with latest MYSQL version with left join also two aggregate functions

Tags: mysql

[image]I have two tables like in above image and third one should be output.

I have tried like this but unable to get the result I can get only one of the columns with category not both at the same time.

This is what I have used:

```
select Budget.Category, sum(Budget.Estimated_Cost) as Estimated_Cost,       
        sum(Actuals.Actual_Cost) as Actual_Cost 
from Budget
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Actuals ON Budget.task = Actuals.Task
GROUP BY Budget.Category;
```

and

```
select b.Category, sum(b.Estimated_Cost) AS Estimated_Cost 
FROM Budget b
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT a.Task 
                FROM Actuals a) x 
        ON x.Task = b.task
GROUP BY b.Category**
```

Answer (score 1):

First aggregate in `Budget` to get the sum of `Estimated_Cost` for each `Category` and then join to `Actuals` and aggregate again to get the sum of `Actual_Cost` that are linked to each `Category`:

```
SELECT b.Category, 
      b.Estimated_Cost,
      SUM(a.Actual_Cost) AS Actual_Cost 
FROM (
  SELECT Category, SUM(Estimated_Cost) Estimated_Cost,
         GROUP_CONCAT(Task) Tasks
  FROM Budget
  GROUP BY Category
) b LEFT JOIN Actuals a
ON FIND_IN_SET(a.Task, b.Tasks)
GROUP BY b.Category, b.Estimated_Cost
```